# APPSTORE: Unable to submit the app for review. The items below are required to start the review process: An error has occurred. Try again later

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, apple-developer

Trying to submit the app for review, but getting the following error [Image Attached].

[image: SEE IMAGE ATTACHED]

All the information is filled.

```
1-> Screenshots are added. 5 for 5.5' and 5 for 6.5'displays.
2-> promotional text, description, Keywords, support URL are filled.
3-> Build is selected, general app information is complete.
4-> Everything seems complete.
```

And there is no error showing on the page. I have also looked at pricing and other things, they seem to be fine too.

Please help if anyone experienced such issue before.

Comment: What web-browser do you use for submitting your app?

Comment: Facing the same problem. Did you find anything? Thanks in advance

Comment: Facing the same problem with one of my apps, not all of them. From which version of Xcode did you build? I submitted using Safari on macOS Big Sur, it's the third one I submit this week, and only one not working.

Comment: I built with Xcode 11.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem while distributing the B2B app via apple business manager. After registering a bank, taxes, and Contacts, the error disappeared.

Goto App Store Connect -> Agreements, Tax, and Banking -> Agree the **Paid Apps** agreement.

[Here you can see why do you need to accept a "Paid Applications" contract when updating free apps?](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/95049)

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue, and the reason is that "Copyright" is required.

Comment: I had same issue and the problem was "Copyright" field to be filled

Answer (score 2):

Access: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/agreements/#/

Fill and accept the terms...
Unfortunately, bank details are now required
i was facing same problem. After fill bank details i had submit build for review

Answer (score 0):

Ensure to go through all the items listed on this menu and provide information as required except in cases mentioned as optional.

In my own case it was category of the application that was missing.

Some sort of attention is needed to provide the complete details also use the tool tip as guide on what to do in areas without clarity.

[image: Apple store connect menu]